# Which is faster, a set comprehension or set difference?

Tags: python, set

I have two lists:

```
from secrets import token_urlsafe

a = [token_urlsafe() for i in range(100)]
b = a[50:]
```

I need to find the difference between the two lists. Do I use a set comprehension, or a set difference?

The Python documentation describes two ways to do this

### Set Difference

`set(a) - set(b)`

> Return a new set with elements in the set that are not in the others
>
> [ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)

### Set Comprehensions

`{i for i in a if i not in b}`

> Use a set comprehension: `{c for c in 'abracadabra' if c not in 'abc'}`
>
> [ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)

Comment: Well, the set comprehension will definitely be slower here because `b` is a *list*. It should be a `set` so fi you do `b = set(a[50:])`

Comment: @khelwood the question is valid because the `set` Python documentation mentions set comprehension and gives a similar example as above without commenting on the performance implications. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga! What prompted this question was that the Python documentation, when using set comprehension doesn't to create a set, doesn't mention casting to a `set` beforehand. Infact, it uses an explicit `string`.

Comment: The quoted Python documentation about set comprehensions is **not** suggesting that you use the example to determine set differences. It's showing the syntax of a comprehension.

Comment: @martineau does the quoted Python documentation about set comprehension have the set effect has a set comprehension? Yes it does. Did I, as a person reading the set documentation, wonder if it would be faster or slower? Yes I did. I expect other people to have the same question, and so I've documented it here on this Q&A site. If you'd like to follow up on this conversation, please feel free to email me off-site. I will no longer be following up here. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see that the set difference method is faster using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: set(a) - set(b), number=100000)
0.37637379999796394

>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: {i for i in a if i not in b}, number=100000)
5.430218600013177
```

Note that the time may vary for the length of set a, the length of set b, and maybe the number of elements in common, and the position for which they're in common.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Regardless of whether it's a scoring tactic, the comparison being done is a bogus because `b` is a list, not a set — which is probably worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @martineau `a` and `b` are both lists. You're welcome to run the code and run a `type` check.

Comment: They're not both sets in the set comprehension.

Comment: @martineau could you please elaborate?

Comment: They are both sets in `set(a) - set(b)`. In `{i for i in a if i not in b}` the variable `b` is a list, so it's doing a very slow linear search through all the elements of the list) — so **of course** it's slower. No surprises here.

Comment: @martineau that's precisely the point in the post. The Python docs, however, fail to mention this when talking about set comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: The [set documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) *does* mention that the elements of a set must be *hashable*, strongly implying that they're implemented via hash tables, which are noteworthy because lookups based on them are independent of the number of elements stored in the table (completely the opposite of a linear search). The point being that not mentioning that fact in another spot in the docs about something unrelated doesn't seem like a very significant omission IMO. Apparently I am not alone in thinking this.

Comment: @martineau the set comprehension example goes on to use a literal `string`. Additionally, "not alone in thinking this" isn't a high enough bar to quash a question on a Q&A site.